# IntelliJ IDEA: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package3:xml/xml.dart'

Tags: dart, intellij-idea

I am new to Dart and stuck at the gate.

I am trying to read a simple XML file but getting this error in IntelliJ IDEA:

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:xml/xml.dart'.

How do I load this package?

I just tried to import the package. I expected to be able to loop through the XML structure, but I need this package loaded properly.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

void main() {
  // Open the XML file
  File file = File('example.xml');
  String contents = file.readAsStringSync();

  // Parse the XML content
  xml.XmlDocument document = xml.parse(contents);

  // Print each element of the parsed XML content to the screen
  for (var element in document.children) {
    print(element.toXmlString(pretty: true));
  }
}
```

And this is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: testxmlread
description: A sample command-line application.
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'

dev_dependencies:
  lints: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.21.0
  xml: ^5.0.0
```

### Update

I have run `dart pub get`, to get the dependencies, but the error persists.

Comment: How are you loading the package? Is this a console command, or Dart code?

Comment: Thank you @halfer I appreciate your message.
I am trying to load via Dart import
import 'dart:io';
import 'package3:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

void main() {
…

Comment: Great stuff. Could you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76111268/edit) with the code snippet? There is a block formatting tool available in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your import. Package imports in Dart take the form `package:package_name/package_name.dart`, but you seem to have `package3:package_name/package_name.dart`.

Try replacing your import with `package:xml/xml.dart` instead.

Comment: I made that change but I don't think I have this package intalled it says: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:xml/xml.dart'.

Comment: Have you also added an entry for `xml` to your `pubspec.yaml` and run `flutter pub get`?

Comment: I added the pubspec.yaml to the question above.  I ran flutter pub get, but it is "Not Found".  I didn't think I needed the Flutter framework for this simple XML file read.  Do I need to install Flutter to read XML?

Comment: Sorry, bad assumption on my end that you were using Flutter. You can just run `dart pub get` instead if you're just using Dart.

Comment: Dart pub get worked to resolve the error.  Thank you Ben.

Answer (score 0):

dart pub get worked.  Thank you Ben Konyi.

Comment: The answer is not necessary